# создание StreamWriter и перенос данных из нескольких элементов в txt файл

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ string filename = @"D:\Text1.txt";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var Кодировка = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
            var Писатель = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, false, Кодировка);
            Писатель.Write("ФИО: " + textBox1.Text + "\n"+ "E-mail: " + textBox2.Text);
            Писатель.Close();
        }
        catch (SystemException Ситуация)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ситуация.Message, "Ошибка",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Давно, мучаюсь с StreamWriter-ом и SreamReader-ом. Буду рад,  если сможете помочь

Comment: Так а в чем проблема то?

Comment: в том,  что не  имею понятия, как перенести эти самые данные элементов так, чтобы получилось как в примере на картинке

Comment: Ещё очень интересен вопрос с GroupBox2. Нужно при отметке radioButton5( c надписью "другая") переводить textBox4 из состояния Enabled = false в true

Comment: Ну вы как то пробовали решить вашу проблему? Может, какие то мысли как это можно сделать были? Вот у вас же, по сути, контролы на форме есть, значения в них есть, то ест считать вы их можете. Чем записывать в файл вы тоже знаете. Потому я и не понял, что вас конкретно затрудняет?

Comment: а зачем вообще тут стрим???

Comment: просто делаеет коллекцию строк в не вставлчяете все что вам надо и потом пишите в файл  там уже все само перенесется и запишится как картинке

Comment: Пожалуйста, укоротите название вопроса и распишите всю проблему в описании

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> fr = new List<string>();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             fr.Add("текст1");
        }

        private void radioButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             fr.Add("текст1");
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              fr.Add("текст1");
        }

        private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              fr.Add("текст1");
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             fr.Add("текст1");
        }

        private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
             fr.Add("текст1");
        }

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C://awd.txt", fr);
```